# JavaScript - messages.load.failed - {"error":"unknown error occurred during Hermes Messages initialization"}

Tags: javascript

Any Idea on how to fix this error message?

messages.load.failed - {"error":"unknown error occurred during Hermes Messages initialization"}

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. It's impossible to help you with this little information. Nothing you mentioned is built into JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

        /* Style the tab */
        div.tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
        div.tab button {
            background-color: inherit;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
        div.tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        /* Create an active/current tablink class */
        div.tab button.active {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        /* Style the tab content */
        .tabcontent {
            display: none;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-top: none;
        }

        tabcontent.iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function openTab(evt, tabName) {
            console.log(tabName );
            // Declare all variables
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

            // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            console.log("tab link size:: " + tablinks.length);
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }

            // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
            document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        }

        document.getElementById("EPSButton").click();
    </script>

    <div class="tab">
        <!-- TAB BUTTONS HERE -->
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'EPS')" id="EPSButton">EPS</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'AMP')" id="AMPButton">AMP</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'InternetON')" id="InternetONButton">InternetON</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TOMI')" id="TOMIButton">TOMI</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Confluence')" id="ConfluenceButton">Confluence</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Broadwork')" id="BroadworkButton">Broadwork</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Frontier')" id="FrontierButton">Frontier</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Optus')" id="OptusButton">Optus</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'AirWatch')" id="AirWatchButton">Airwatch</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'InterfaceIT')" id="InterfaceITButton">InterfaceIT</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'TinyURL')" id="TinyURLButton">TinyURL</button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Radius')" id="RadiusButton">Radius</button>
        <!-- TAB BUTTONS HERE -->
    </div>

    <!-- iFRAMES HERE -->

    <div id="EPS" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://portal.emapta.com/"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="AMP" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://management.anex.com.au/Customer/ByService/"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="InternetON" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://management.anex.com.au/ION/Dashboard"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="TOMI" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://management.anex.com.au/TOM/Dashboard"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="Confluence" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://acurus.atlassian.net"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="Broadwork" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://www.hostedclient.com.au/callcenter/"></iframe>
    </div>

     <div id="Frontier" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://frontier.aapt.com.au/"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="Optus" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://www.optus.com.au/wholesalenet/"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="AirWatch" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="http://cn500.airwatchpor­­tals.com"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="InterfaceIT" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://console.interfaceit.com"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="TinyURL" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="https://tinyurl.com"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div id="Radius" class="tabcontent">
        <iframe src="http://URL"></iframe>
    </div>



    <!-- iFRAMES HERE -->
</body>
```

Comment: If you want to add more information to your question, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46333921/edit). Stack Overflow is not a forum. What you posted is not an answer to your question. Also, code without an explanation is not useful.